# E-Commerce website cart logic

Tags: node.js, logic, e-commerce

I'm building an E-commerce website on node.js in which I need to implement cart, wherein a user can add products to cart without loging in like amazon and when he signs in those products should automatically get added to the cart, At present I'm adding cart to the user session .Can anyone help me with the flow.

```
    var cart = [];

    function add_to_cart(req, res, next) {
    db.arts.findOne(query, function(err, art) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        if (!art) {
            return res.status(404).send({
                error: 'Art not found'
            });
        }
        if (req.session.user) {
            var user_id = req.session.user._id;
        }
        var cart_detail = {
            art_id: art._id,
            price: art.price,
        };
        if (cart.length !== 0) {
            var arrayTrue = true;
            req.session.cart.forEach(function(data) {
                if (data.art_id == req.params._id) {
                    arrayTrue = false;
                }
            });
            console.log(arrayTrue);
            if (arrayTrue) {
                // Doesn't exist...
                console.log("dosent exist");
                cart.push(cart_detail);
                req.session.cart = cart;
                return res.send(req.session.cart);
            } else {
                return res.send({
                    error: "Art already present in your cart"
                });
            }
        }
        cart.push(cart_detail);
        req.session.cart = cart;
        console.log(req.session.cart);
        return res.send(req.session.cart);
    });
 }
```